# I cant use certain linux commands in a bash script altough I can use them in console

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script that utilizes the command `mkvirtualenv`.

I can use it in the console without a problem but as soons I as try to use it in a bash script I get `./run: line 1: mkvirtualenv: command not found`

I am not aware of anything that would create such a situation.
Does anyone know why the bash script behaves like that?

Comment: Try `type mkvirtualenv` in the terminal to see how the shell resolves the command. Maybe it's an alias?

Comment: @choroba `root@home:~# type mkvirualenv
-bash: type: mkvirualenv: not found` - Thats so weird..

Comment: missing `t`. `type mkvirtualenv`

Comment: @choroba `mkvirtualenv is a function` - http://pastebin.com/qu3chLVn

Answer (score 0):

The reason emerged form the comments below the question: `mkvirtualenv` is a function.

If you want the function to exist in the script, you can export it from your shell by

```
export -f mkvirtualenv
```

Comment: He could also use a sane shell setup and avoid defining functions inside interactive shells :D

Comment: So thats extremely weird: `./test: line 1: export: mkvirtualenv: not a function`

Comment: @Dr.Cru: You have to export the function from a shell that knows it, not from a script that doesn't know it.